# Fatal Python error/ImportError When Upgrading

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, package-management, python

When attempting `apt upgrade` or `apt update-manager` I receive the following error:

```
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fa215e86700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've read through the many duplicate questions, and none of the solutions have worked for me.

Using Ubuntu 14.04, with Python 2.7.12 default, I manually installed Python 3.5 from source. I have never used a virtual environment to deal with the multiple versions. Since I'm very new to Ubuntu, I without thinking deleted many files and directories for Python3.5 from `/usr/lib` though there are still Python3 and Python3.5 files in `/usr/bin`. Despite the fatal error, Python 2.7.12 still works perfectly in shell, and `python -V` still says 2.7.12 is the default version.

The above error results after unsetting both `$PYTHONHOME` and `$PYTHONPATH`. If `echo $PYTHONHOME` returns nothing, and then I enter `PYTHONHOME` in the command line, I receive the following error (likewise for entering `PYTHONPATH`):

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f57373f3700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I enter `which python` the command line returns `/usr/bin/python`, and that file does have as its link target Python2.7. If I then set `export PYTHONHOME=/usr` and again enter `PYTHONHOME` into the command line, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f3de267e700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I move my command line directory to my python directory and enter `python -m encodings` I receive the following:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named encodings.__main__; 'encodings' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

...so I'm not even sure how I would make `PYTHONPATH` aware of it as a module if it apparently is not a module. And regardless of how I set `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`, I have so far continued to get the same error when I run `apt upgrade`.

Some other fixes I've attempted:

- All these commands run without a problem, but do not fix the error

  ```
  apt update
  apt clean
  apt autoclean
  ```
- `apt autoremove` and `apt-get -f install` both yield the same error as `apt upgrade`
- unsetting `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` does not fix the error, nor does setting `PYTHONHOME` to the directory indicated by `which python`
- I attempted to use the Synaptic package manager to fix broken packages, but this didn't fix the error.
- I checked to make sure that `/usr/lib/command-not-found` explicitly calls `/usr/bin/python3`, and that file does exist (I didn't delete it).
- My `/lost+found` directory is currently empty, so there are no modules to restore from there.
- Using `apt-get install --reinstall python` (and the same command with `python3.5`) yields the same error as `apt upgrade`.

I've found no other resources or answers to deal with this error. Should I try using a virtual environment to isolate the remaining files of my python versions? Should I attempt to fix my now corrupted manual installations of python3.5, and how would I do so since `--reinstall python` yields a fatal error?

Comment: One does not simply delete libraries from `/usr/lib`

Comment: I realize that this is all my fault and I shouldn't have mucked around deleting protected files, but does anyone have any advice on how I could better format or phrase this question? I tried to exhaustively search through all the duplicate questions and provide as much info as I could.